# Can not build the B2G desktop client (./mach build) ' . ' is not recognized as an internal

Tags: command, prompt, firefox-os, b2g

I'm trying to build the Mozilla B2G Desktop client by following this guide: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox_OS/Building_the_B2G_desktop_client.

I've already cloned the mozilla-central repository using:
`hg clone http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central` on the command prompt and it was successful.

Then I created the **mozconfig** file in the *mozilla-central* directory and the next step was to build the desktop client by running the command prompt from inside the *mozilla-cental* directory and the executing the following command: `./mach build` but I haven't been able to get past this step because this is what the command prompt says when I try to run that command:

```
C:\Users\Droid\mozilla-central>./mach build
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Users\Droid\mozilla-central>
```

Can someone please help me get past this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`./mach` is a command that is supposed to be run in a `sh`-like shell, i.e. *not* `cmd.exe`.

1. You need to install [MozillaBuild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Windows_Prerequisites#Install_build_prerequisites). This brings a lot of different tools.
2. Within the installation directory, there will be some `start-shell*.bat` files. Start the one which corresponds with your compiler. This will not only setup a proper environment but also start a `sh`-like shell (a Windows port of bash taken from msys, if anybody is curious).
3. Navigate to your checkout folder.
4. Setup `mozconfig`.
5. `./mach build`

Please refer to the general [Build instructions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions) for further information.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I already had it installed but I wasn't sure which terminal to use. Now I actually started building the desktop client.